# Recovering Grub after installing windows 8.1

Tags: grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I installed Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu 12.04.

Now, grub does not shows up any more! It's goes straight to Windows after turning my PC on.

Grub gone after installing Windows 8.1

Please tell me what should I do to turn grub back ?

Any helps would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to install grub again with an Live CD.
This [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) could help you

Answer (score 2):

use easy.bcd in windows.download easy bcd from Internet run it on your windows now from the side bar select add new entry then go to Linux in upper tabs select grub 2 write name Ubuntu and select add it's done.
now whenever you boot from next time you will see two options name windows8 and ubuntu select that one in which you want to go

Comment: can you include a link in your answer to the program you are recommending?

Comment: I had this problem too, I booted into BIOs then went to the "Starup Order" tab. There I saw "Windows Boot Loader" as position 1 and "ubuntu" in position 2. Switch the order, save and exit. And you'll see the grub again! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier method if you don't have a LiveCD on hand. Just go to your Bios settings and put Ubuntu back into the first boot slot. It takes about five seconds. If you have UEFI activated then you'll have to log on to Windows and reboot into the Bios, but it's not hard.