# My Ubuntu disappeared!

Tags: 12.04

I've choosed to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8. When I started up my computer, I saw GRUB and i could choose between Windows 7 and Edubuntu 12.04. But now, when I start up computer, it's just booting Windows 8! (I haven't formatted or anything like that) Please help me!

Comment: This should be able to help you.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/370910/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy fix:
1) Download and install EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
2) Open it
3) Go to "Add New Entry"
4) Select "Linux", "GRUB 2", and click on "Add" button 
5) Restart your PC and enter Ubuntu
6) Optional: Once you are inside Ubuntu run "sudo grub-install /dev/sda" to reinstall grub and set it as your default boot manager

Comment: not a great idea to use grub as it does not play nice with windows installations at ALL.